# Parent-Member Indication that 1 (or more) Children are currently selected in a multiselect filter

Tags: sharepoint-2010, performancepoint

Is there a setting for PerformancePoint multi-select filters that will give the user a visual queue that child members are currently selected?

For example, in the image below, "2012-Week02" is the selected child-member.  When "2012", the parent-member, is collaps, I would like to see a visual queue (grey checkbox, bold text, etc) to let me know that there's a child in this path that is currently selected.

[image]

Like Excel...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but this is being corrected in PerformancePoint Services 2013.  See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/performancepoint/archive/2012/08/03/what-s-new-in-performancepoint-services-2013.aspx)